# Set redux-form Field value based on TWO other fields

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

So, in redux-form, I have seen many ways of updating a `Field`'s value based on another `Field`. My particular situation is updating a `Field`'s value based on **two** different `Fields`.

The two popular ways suggested to achieve this are 1.) [redux-form's normalizer](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/normalizing/), and 2.) manually dispatching redux-form's [change](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/actioncreators.md/) method to change `Field3`'s value, when the `onChange` for `Field1` is called. Both these solutions do not seem to be working for me for the following reasons:

1. **Normalizer**: Let's say I have 3 fields - `Field1`, `Field2` and `Field3`. I need to set the value of `Field3` when either of `Field1` or `Field2` are changed. **Also the value of `Field2` is automatically set when `Field1` is changed**. Let's say I define a normalizer on `Field1`, which checks the values of the entire form. In this case, inside my normalizer function, `Field1`'s value gets updated, but `Field2` retains it's old value. This could be some odd behavior from redux-form maybe.
2. **Manually dispatching redux-form's change method on `Field3`, from inside `Field1`'s or `Field2`'s `onChange`** - The problem with this is that if I try to access `Field1`'s value inside `Field1`'s `onChange`, the method passed to `Field1`'s `onChange` retains `Field1`'s old value. Hence I can't reliably set the value of `Field3` based on `Field1`'s new value.

Any suggestions as to how to approach this would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create a component for field3 (say Field3) and use it in the form like this

```
<Field name="field3" component={Field3} />
```

in Field3 component we also inject the field1 and field2 value to Field3 component. so that whenever the component updated we can check if it's because of field1 or field2 then we update field3 accordingly:

```
import React from 'react';
import { formValues } from 'redux-form';

class Field3 extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.field1 !== prevProps.field1 || this.props.field2 !== prevProps.field2) {
      // field1 or field2 has changed. update field3
      this.props.input.onChange('new value goes here')
    }
  }

  render() {
    // your input here
  }
}

export default formValues('field1', 'field2')(Field3);
```